# Flask & Python creating a JSON object

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to familiarize myself with Python, coming from a heavy PHP background. I want to create a JSON object that returns the following:

```
Endpoint: /dashboard
Request params:{ 
                   method:”get”,
                   headers:headers,
                   url:string,
                   data:{
                           userId: string,
                           date: int
                        }
}

Response: (JSON Object)
{
     code: 200/400,
     message: String,
     data: {     
                  totalCal:
                  remainingCal:
               }
}
```

Essentially connecting to the database and returning a 200 if the data matches, a 400 if i hit any errors. I came up with this so far, but I'd appreciate any input on how I could perform this better!

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET'])
def availCalories():
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT remaining_cal FROM daily_cal WHERE user_id = 1 AND day= curdate();''')# WHERE userID=userID in session???
    row_headers=[x[0] for x in cur.description]  #EXTRACT ROW HEADERS
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    json_data=[]
    for result in rv:
        json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
    return json.dumps(json_data)
```

I've been teaching myself Python for only 3 months now, so a lot of this is trial and error, but I find myself hitting a wall with this!

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving already-working code belong on [codereview.se], not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `flask` so you can also investigate the `jsonify` method, which is convenient and common:

> flask.json.jsonify(*args, **kwargs)
>
> This function wraps dumps() to add a few enhancements that make life easier. It turns the JSON output into a Response object with the application/json mimetype. For convenience, it also converts multiple arguments into an array or multiple keyword arguments into a dict. This means that both jsonify(1,2,3) and jsonify([1,2,3]) serialize to [1,2,3].

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the input.